# Android Manifest - Facebook Common

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I have a perfectly running Android Project and Now after a month now I am trying to build the project it gives me errors on Android Manifest merger errors.

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong.

Error Message:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuxlJ.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently update build-tools or gradle version? if yes, try downgrading the version.

Comment: No, I haven't updated the build-tools or Gradle version but downgrading the facebook-sdk version from 14.1.1 to 14.1.0 serves the purpose.